# Function or dict comprehension as a Snakefile output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, snakemake

I have a Snakemake rule with a highly redundant output (here simplified):

```
rule redundant:
    output:
        a_x = "prefix_a_x.ext"
        b_x = "prefix_b_x.ext"
        a_y = "prefix_a_y.ext"
        b_y = "prefix_b_y.ext"
    run:
        process_1(output.a_x)
        process_2(output.a_y)
        process_3(output.b_x)
        process_4(output.b_y)
```

I can remove redundancy at the cost of the readability:

```
rule less_readable:
    output:
        [f"prefix_{a}_{b}.ext"
         for a in ["a", "b"]
         for b in ["x", "y"]]
    run:
        process_1(output[0])
        process_2(output[1])
        process_3(output[2])
        process_4(output[3])
```

(I do not want to risk use of the
`expand("prefix_{a}_{b}.ext", a=["a", "b"], b=["x", "y"])`
as the order of outputs matters and I fear it may change
in future Snakemake versions.)

I would like to have the best of two worlds, something like:

```
rule more_readable:
    output:
        {f"{a}_{b}": f"prefix_{a}_{b}.ext"
         for a in ["a", "b"]
         for b in ["x", "y"]}
    run:
        process_1(output.a_x)
        process_2(output.a_y)
        process_3(output.b_x)
        process_4(output.b_y)
```

Sadly, that does not work:

```
$ snakemake -j 1 prefix_a_x.ext
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce prefix_a_x.ext (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

How can I assign labels to automatically generated targets?

I use

```
$ snakemake --version
7.14.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You last snippet is almost correct, make sure to use the dictionary expansion (`**`):

```py
rule more_readable:
    output:
        **{f"{a}_{b}": f"prefix_{a}_{b}.ext"
         for a in ["a", "b"]
         for b in ["x", "y"]}
```

Comment: Nice! `**` is python syntax but is it also in the snakemake docs?

Comment: Nope, I haven't seen it mentioned explicitly.

Comment: It's unfortunate it's not documented. Using a dictionary is pretty cool but I'd say it's really tricky to figure out you need `**`

Comment: LOL, I have almost tried that, but I had thought "nah, I am overthinking".  Are sections of a rule (`input:`, `output:`, etc.) implemented to be interpreted as arguments of Python functions?  I do remember _Snakemake_ was complaining when I gave a "keyword argument" before a "positional argument".